# What syntax does the Current Language property take in a SQL Server connection string?

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) says:

> Sets the language used for database
>   server warning or error messages.
>
> The language name can be 128
>   characters or less.

Which tells me zip about the actual format I'm supposed to use. Does it take a numeric LCID? A textual language name? In what format? en-US? English? Is it case sensitive? And so on.

And I presume "Current Language" and "Language" are equivalent for the purposes of that property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords) says

> The SQL Server Language record name.

So it will be one of the values you'd use for [SET LANGUAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx) which in turn comes from [sys.syslanguages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190303.aspx)

Comment: I now have a sub-question, sparked by your answer... does specifying this setting in the connection string also affect how dates, days of weeks, etc. will be handled by the connection?

Comment: @lazydba: I'm sure it does. It *is* SET LANGUAGE from .net so affects date formats at least. But not @@DATEFIRST